# How to change image in first fragment when I pressed back button from the second fragment

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I want to change an image( i.e @+id/shower) in first fragment (this fragment was added to viewpager) when I backpress from second fragment this fragment is replaced by first fragment second child(Relative layout i.e @+id/view_frame )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame_indicators"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

    >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp10"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp10"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shower"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/first_plan_indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </ImageView>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/navi_selector"
            android:id="@+id/choose_plan_text"
            android:text="Choose Plans"/>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/enter_details_text"

            android:text="Enter Details"/>
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/pay_text"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:text="Payment"/>


    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_frame"

    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frame_indicators"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_type"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:id="@+id/for_family"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="For Your Family">        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/family_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp5"
            android:background="@color/navi_selector"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:id="@+id/for_you"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="For You">        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/your_divider"

            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/navi_selector"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs_type"
        android:id="@+id/packageslist_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and My code inside FIRST FRAGMET, when I am calling second fragment(registerfragment), I am able to change image by calling indicatorChangesNew() method.

```
         if (packagesList.getPackageID()==6)
         {
            planListFragmentNew.indicatorChangesNew(1);
        }
        else
    {
        planListFragmentNew.indicatorChangesNew(2);
    } 
    FragmentManager fragmanger=mContext.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragtrans;
    fragtrans = fragmanger.beginTransaction();
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("planCost",packagesList.getPackageCost());
    b.putString("planName",packagesList.getPackageName());
    b.putString("paymode",packagesList.getPackageModeOfPay());
    b.putInt("planId",packagesList.getPackageID());
    b.putString("role",packagesList.getRolePatient());
    RegisterFragment registerFragment=new RegisterFragment();
    registerFragment.setArguments(b);
    fragtrans.replace(R.id.view_frame, registerFragment);
    fragtrans.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAG_TAG_REGISTER);
    fragtrans.commit();
```

And my indicatorChangesNew() method is

```
    public void indicatorChangesNew(int  checkValue)
   {if (checkValue==1)
    {      mChoosePlanText.setTextColor(getResources()
    .getColor(R.color.textcolor));
          mEnterPlanText.setTextColor(getResources()
        .getColor(R.color.navi_selector));
        mPayText.setTextColor(getResources()
     .getColor(R.color.textcolor));
        mShower.setImageDrawable(getResources()
     .getDrawable(R.drawable.second_plan_indicator));
      }
    else if(checkValue==2)
    {
        mChoosePlanText.setTextColor(getResources().
      getColor(R.color.textcolor));
        mEnterPlanText.setTextColor(getResources()
      .getColor(R.color.textcolor));
        mPayText.setTextColor(getResources()

      .getColor(R.color.navi_selector));
        mShower.setImageDrawable(getResources()
   .getDrawable(R.drawable.third_plan_indicator));
    }
    else{
           mChoosePlanText.setTextColor(getResources()
      .getColor(R.color.navi_selector));
    mEnterPlanText.setTextColor(getResources()
   .getColor(R.color.textcolor));
    mPayText.setTextColor(getResources()
     .getColor(R.color.textcolor));
    mShower.setImageDrawable(getResources()
 .getDrawable(R.drawable.first_plan_indicator));}
}
```

Comment: I want to call indicatorChangesNew() it is inside PlanListFragment when pressed back button from RegisterFragment.

Answer (score 0):

use shared preferences or a singleton class or just a static variable.

Comment: I want to call indicatorChangesNew() when I pressed back button from RegisterFragment, please give clear answer if it is possible give one sample.  Thanku